# problem connecting to a global server from graphql client react native

Tags: android, react-native, graphql, apollo-client

I have a problem with using GraphQL, When I try to connect my local server it works fine, but when I use it on a global server with a valid domain name, it says "network request failed". I also checked the server logs, it didn't receive any request.
Server works fine, I checked it using the browser (graphiql).

I don't know where is the problem, is there something blocking outbound traffic in android devices that I'm not aware of?

Comment: tested using postman?

Comment: yes, tested in the browser (not different from postman in this case). server works fine.

Comment: not, this is not the same, postman is an external client, graphiql is not external (the same domain/origin) - auth reasons?

Comment: thanks, I tried postman, and I received a 405 code error! I don't know how to fix that,  but the worse is I checked my nginx logs from the server and realized that I doesn't even get a request from android device, it get postman requests though.